# How to apply for jobs in Australia for overseas graduate?

Tags: working-visas, australia, working

Let say I am a recent graduate in a technological field in 2018, for instance AI, and I want to work from 6 months to a lifetime in Australia. Having seen that most job offers require people to have a work visa, I have been visiting the work visas [webpage](https://www.australia.gov.au/information-and-services/immigration-and-visas/work-visas) of the Australian government. Then, one can't know if he has to apply for skilled visa with the [SkillSelect program](https://www.homeaffairs.gov.au/Trav/Work/Skil) or another. Yet, for this program one has to be nominated by an approved Australian employer.

There seem to be a contradiction then : I can't present a valid working visa to a company asking me to have one if I have first to be approved for it.

Subquestion : do you know websites for Australian job offers for just graduated students ?

Answer (score 1):

You can ask your potential employer whether they are prepared to sponsor a temporary work visa for you.  If they really want to hire you and are a large employer with the resources to sponsor foreigners, they can sponsor you for a [subclass 482 visa](https://www.homeaffairs.gov.au/trav/visa-1/482-) (which replaced the old [subclass 457 visa](https://www.homeaffairs.gov.au/Trav/Visa-1/457-/)).  These visas allow you to stay and work temporarily for a number of years.

Once you are in Australia and worked for that employer for a number of years, you can ask them to sponsor you for permanent residency via the [Employer Nomination Scheme (subclass 186) visa](https://www.homeaffairs.gov.au/trav/visa-1/186-).

Comment: While you can always ask, the unfortunate truth is that few companies will be willing to sponsor a work visa for a fresh grad with no work experience -- although graduating from a hot field like AI helps.